No option name near , Error parsing a filter description around
I am trying to attach the captions files ( srt format ) to a video
if im running the same command on mac or windows, its working with -vf or -filter_complex but on android/IOS, its not working and throwing the same error
i am on Flutter and here is my code :
var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}

final outputPath = "${tempDir.path}/outputWithCaptions.mp4";


const videoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/english.mp4";
final subtitlePath = deepGramResponse.captionsPath.replaceAll('\'', '\\\'');
String command = "-y -i";
command = "$command '$videoPath'";
command = "$command -vf";
command = '$command "subtitles=\'$subtitlePath\'"';
command = "$command '$outputPath'";
 if (File(videoPath).existsSync() && File(subtitlePath).existsSync()) {
  FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command, (session) async {
    final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
    final output = await session.getOutput();
    final error = await session.getFailStackTrace();
    final logs = await session
        .getAllLogs()
        .then((value) => value.map((e) => e.getMessage()).toList());
    log('FFmpeg command executed with return code: $returnCode');
    if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
      log('Captions attached successfully');
      deepGramResponse.copyWith(
        videoPath: outputPath,
      );
      Get.to(() => VideoPlayerScreen(videoPath: outputPath));
    } else {
      log('FFmpeg command failed');
      log('Error output: $output');
      log('Error details: $error');
      log('Logs: $logs');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Something went wrong, please try again later');
    }
  });
} else {
  log('One or more files do not exist');
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Subtitle or video file not found');
  return;
}

and here is the error :
 , [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7b8a3dda90] No option name near '/data/user/0/com.example.blink/app_flutter/captions.srt'
  , [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7b8a3dda90] Error parsing a filter description around: 
  , [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7b8a3dda90] Error parsing filterchain 'subtitles='/data/user/0/com.example.blink/app_flutter/captions.srt'' around: 
  , Error reinitializing filters!
  , Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
  , Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
  , Conversion failed!

